# How much strip(1)-ing is okay for kernel modules?

Tags: kernel-modules, strip

I regularly create packages for Slackware Linux and part of the process is stripping binaries so that they take up less space. I find that if I `strip --strip-all` (or `strip` with no options) kernel modules, they often fail to insert:

> FATAL: Error inserting cloop (/lib/modules/2.6.38.7-smp/kernel/fs/cloop/cloop.ko): Invalid module format

What level of stripping is recommended for kernel modules? If I use `--strip-debug`, will I remove debugging symbols that will negatively affect system performance and/or error logging?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Stripping all symbols removes the names of the symbols that the module calls. It's not going to work.

Stripping debugging symbols with `strip --strip-debug *.ko` (= `strip -g *.ko`) is safe. The kernel makefile does it for you if you run `make INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 modules_install`.

You can prevent debugging symbols being inserted in the first place by configuring your kernel with `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO` not defined.

See also [How do I strip local symbols from linux kernel module without breaking it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895816/how-do-i-strip-local-symbols-from-linux-kernel-module-without-breaking-it)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the safest approach is `strip --strip-unneeded`.

Comment: I see that `--strip-unneeded` also strips `.modinfo` section, including the 'module depends' and the 'vermagic' things. Unsure what would be the consequences.