# What happens if I strip kernel modules?

Tags: linux-kernel

I realize that stripping kernel modules significantly reduces the size of initrd.

What really happens if I strip the kernel modules?

Answer (score 0):

Stripping linux kernel module objects is possible but you need to take attention that you can’t use the default parameters. You can only strip debugging symbols from kernel objects with --strip-debug parameter:
Here is below the link to see detailed discussions for your question.

[How much strip(1)-ing is okay for kernel modules?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25421/how-much-strip1-ing-is-okay-for-kernel-modules)